# ln transformed data: how to report lme results in original units

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme

I conducted an experiment to observe the effect a repeated treatment had on the concentration of protein in a set of samples. I have no formal training in statistics.

My goal is to report how much protein is lost per treatment, and to condense this into a prediction for how much one might expect to lose at any given treatment.

I thought a linear mixed model would be an appropriate method to use, and created a model in R using the lme function of the nlme package (ver 3.1-118).

Problem: to meet model assumptions I transformed data by ln. I do not understand what the results mean in terms of my units of interest (pg/mL - protein concentration).

My code (should be plug and play):

```
# packages
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)

# data vectors
Sample <- c("S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S14.1", "S14.1", "S14.1", "S14.1", "S14.1", "S14.1", "S14.1", "S14.1", "S14.2", "S14.2", "S14.2", "S14.2", "S14.2", "S14.2", "S14.2", "S14.2", "S14.3", "S14.3", "S14.3", "S14.3", "S14.3", "S14.3", "S14.3", "S14.3", "S15.1", "S15.1", "S15.1", "S15.1", "S15.1", "S15.1", "S15.1", "S15.1", "S15.2", "S15.2", "S15.2", "S15.2", "S15.2", "S15.2", "S15.2", "S15.2", "S15.3", "S15.3", "S15.3", "S15.3", "S15.3", "S15.3", "S15.3", "S15.3")
Treatment <- c( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)    
ProtConc <- c(244, 160, 143, 129, 102, 91.1, 76.6, 58, 148, 85.3, 75.2, 60.9, 55.6, 41.9, 33.2, 27.9, 303, 205, 136, 114, 89.6, 71.9, 52.4, 42.6, 210, 124, 114, 94.1, 76.9, 56.1, 50.4, 38.5, 566, 431, 358, 287, 254, 193, 158, 113, 374, 239.5, 188, 150.5, 133.5, 102, 69.35, 51.85, 307, 193, 174.5, 160, 121, 87.25, 74.95, 57.2, 324.5, 219.5, 161, 161.5, 126, 106, 77.15, 59.85, 534, 316.5, 270.5, 209, 161.5, 127, 99.7, 74.9, 454, 280, 244.5, 197.5, 172.5, 130, 105, 67.7, 514, 252.5, 244.5, 217, 162, 126, 98.6, 77.3)
lnProt <- c(5.497168225, 5.075173815, 4.96284463, 4.859812404, 4.624972813, 4.511957804, 4.338597077, 4.060443011, 4.997212274, 4.446174454, 4.320151231, 4.109233175, 4.018183201, 3.735285827, 3.502549876, 3.328626689, 5.713732806, 5.323009979, 4.912654886, 4.736198448, 4.49535532, 4.275276265, 3.958906591, 3.751854253, 5.347107531, 4.820281566, 4.736198448, 4.544358047, 4.342505877, 4.027135813, 3.919991175, 3.650658241, 6.338594078, 6.06610809, 5.880532986, 5.659482216, 5.537334267, 5.262690189, 5.062595033, 4.727387819, 5.924255797, 5.478553417, 5.236441963, 5.013963084, 4.894101478, 4.624972813, 4.239166147, 3.948354935, 5.726847748, 5.262690189, 5.161924742, 5.075173815, 4.795790546, 4.468777561, 4.316821225, 4.046553898, 5.782285536, 5.391352233, 5.081404365, 5.084505143, 4.836281907, 4.663439094, 4.345751579, 4.091841432, 6.280395839, 5.757323242, 5.600272098, 5.342334252, 5.084505143, 4.844187086, 4.602165677, 4.316153891, 6.118097198, 5.634789603, 5.499215309, 5.285738584, 5.150397236, 4.86753445, 4.65396035, 4.21508618, 6.242223265, 5.531411249, 5.499215309, 5.379897354, 5.087596335, 4.836281907, 4.591071262, 4.347693956)


# data frame
df <- data.frame(Sample, Treatment, ProtConc, lnProt)
dftreat <- as.factor(df$Treatment)

# mixed model
mod1 <- lme(ProtConc ~ Treatment, random = ~1|Sample, data=df)
summary(mod1)
intervals(mod1)

# assumption tests
plot(mod1)
hist(residuals(mod1))
qqnorm(residuals(mod1)); qqline(residuals(mod1))
agostino.test(df$ProtConc)

# graph
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dftreat, y=ProtConc, group=Sample)) + 
geom_line(aes(colour=df$Sample, linetype=df$Sample), size=1) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,600), breaks=seq(0,600, 50)) +
labs(title="Effect of repeated treatment on protein concentration", x="Treatment", y="Concentration (pg/mL)", 
   linetype="Sample", colour="Sample")
```

The 'assumption tests' show that data violate model assumptions of linearity and normality. This can also be seen in the graph, the first treatment clearly has a greater effect than subsequent treatments.

The data is playing hardball. Transform it by ln:

```
# mixed model ln
mod2 <- lme(lnProt ~ Treatment, random = ~1|Sample, data=df)
summary(mod2)
intervals(mod2)

# assumption tests
plot(mod2)
hist(residuals(mod2))
qqnorm(residuals(mod2)); qqline(residuals(mod2))
agostino.test(df$lnProt)

# graph
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dftreat, y=lnProt, group=Sample)) + 
geom_line(aes(colour=df$Sample, linetype=df$Sample), size=1) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10), breaks=seq(0,10, 1)) +
labs(title="Effect of repeated treatment on ln protein concentration", x="Treatment", y="Concentration (pg/mL)", 
   linetype="Sample", colour="Sample")
```

Great, assumption tests suggest data are now model compatible.

As I understand it, the coefficient -0.232904 describes the slope of the difference between treatments, and is my model's prediction of the effect of any given treatment event based on the data.

However, the coefficient should be exponentiated to transform it back into the original unit (pg/mL). 2.718281828^-0.232904 = 0.7922

This does not look even nearly sensible, and clearly I misunderstand something. Presumably one can treat 0.7922 as a negative value, but the average effect of treatment is manifestly not -0.7922 pg/mL.

I would gratefully appreciate your time and help in explaining where I am going wrong.

It would also be great to know how to get an output showing the coefficient between each consecutive treatment.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting to close/move to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). Since I'm impatient ...

Short answer: the exponentiated coefficient is not a *linear* change per unit of change in `Treatment`, but a *multiplicative* change (i.e., every 1-unit change in `Treatment` leads to *multiplying* the protein concentration by 0.79, or an approximately 21% decrease). For small values of the coefficient, you can read them directly (approximately) as a proportional change, so if you said "-0.23, that means approximately a 23% decrease" you would have been in the ballpark (off by 0.02 in the rate of change, or about 10% off in *relative* terms).